# Почему функция не выводится?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    document.write("<img class='row_size' src='img/' + RandomPics() />");
</script>
```

Сама функция:

```js
var pics = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg', '8.jpg', '9.jpg', '10.jpg', 
        '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '20.jpg', 
        '21.jpg', '22.jpg', '23.jpg', '24.jpg', '25.jpg', '26.jpg', '27.jpg', '28.jpg', '29.jpg', '30.jpg', 
        '31.jpg', '32.jpg', '33.jpg', '34.jpg', '35.jpg', '36.jpg', '37.jpg', '38.jpg', '39.jpg', '40.jpg' ];

 function RandomPics() {
     return pics[Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length)];
 }
```

Comment: флешмоб получился

Comment: с такими вопросами иначе и не получится=)

Answer (score 5):

```
document.write("<img class='row_size' src='img/" + RandomPics() + "'/>");
```

Comment: не работает. А с функции есть ошибка???

Comment: выведи сороку, которая получается из "<img class='row_size' src='img/' + RandomPics() />"

Comment: проверил минуту назад все работает, вывело: <img class="row_size" src="img/16.jpg"/>

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write("<img class='row_size' src='img/' " + RandomPics() + " />");
```

Comment: не работает. А с функции есть ошибка???

Comment: Неверно. С апострофами и пробелом наврал.